# Could we set async type in React stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

I have React stateless function as below :

```
  const func = () => {
    const fetchedPosts = getPost();

    const posts = fetchedPosts.map((item, i) =>
      <Post {...item} />
    );
  return (
    <div>
     {posts}
    </div>
  );
 }
```

But when i run the code i get following error in console:

```
fetchedPosts undefined
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
```

Its because getPost() is a promise and the react component do not wait until the promise resolved.

I tried to use

```
 const func = async () => {
   const fetchedPosts = await getPost();
   ...
```

But got same error.

does react component support async/await feature ?

Comment: You shouldn't do data requests in an UI component. They should just display the data

Comment: You're conflicting yourself, it's not a "stateless" component if it has internal state, which it does in your case.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha its a stateless component .. it doesn't has an internal state

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so what's your suggestion ?
Do i should change it to normal component instead of stateless and use state to handle it ?